# $\omega^\omega$ correspondence with $\mathbb R$-irrationality

Tags: continuity, real-numbers, integers, natural-numbers

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053150/omega-omega-correspondence-with-mathbb-r) in the second comment I do not understand why $\omega^\omega$ corresponds to **irrational** numbers? :
In my experience one typically identifies $ω^ω$ with the irrational elements of R; and then we call them "reals" because they are equinumerous, and in particular "isomorphic up to a countable set".

**QUESTION:** What can we say about irrationality of $f=(2,2,2,2,...)$ goes to $(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,...)$
which is *not* irrational since it repeats the $0,0,1$ pattern forever,right? And yet, it doesn't end wiht eventually all $1$'s.

Comment: The usual correspondence maps elements of $\omega^\omega$ to infinite continued fractions, i.e., irrationals in $(0,1)$. It is not clear at all what the example you give is supposed to be.

Comment: The mapping that Noah Schweber gave in his post is not the one I was talking about. He does *mention* the one I was talking about in the sentence right before: it is the mapping that takes $(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots)$ to $\frac 1{a_1 + \frac1{a_2 + \frac1{a_3 + \cdots}}}$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That explains my question, at least partially. However, how do I **prove** that all such $f's$ from $\omega$ to $\omega$ get map to **irrationals** via this continued fractions? What if there is a tail of $0$'s? Do they also map to irrational numbers?

Comment: In particular, $(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \ldots)$ goes to an $x$ satisfying $x = \frac1{2 + x}$, so $x = \sqrt2 - 1$.

Comment: OK. But what about $(2,0,0,0,0,0,0....)$ ?

Comment: Yes, they all map to irrational numbers. (My definition is slightly wrong if $0$ is a natural number: then you have to add 1 to each $a_i$ before forming the continued fraction.) In general, I recommend reading up on continued fractions/continued fraction expansions.

Comment: $\omega$ is an ordinal, am I the only one bothered by this mixing of notations between sets and ordinals when talking about mappings... Anyway, you can have a look at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146599/encode-each-n-1-n-2-n-3-%e2%88%88nn-by-an-in%ef%ac%81nite-sequence-of-0s-and-1s-with-in%ef%ac%81ni/2146795#2146795

Comment: @zwim The OP is using the notation **correctly**: ordinals are sets, and in particular $\omega$ is the set of all finite ordinals, and is generally used instead of "$\mathbb{N}$" in logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above, you're conflating two different homeomorphisms between $\omega^\omega$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. It seems you're most interested in the continued fraction map, so let me say a bit about that one.

Given an infinite sequence $A=(a_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of natural numbers - which in logic include $0$, so you'll see some "$1+$"s here which you won't in other contexts - the corresponding continued fraction is $$F_A=(1+a_0)+{1\over (1+a_1)+{1\over (1+a_2)+{1\over ...}}}.$$ The following is a basic fact about continued fractions (and *not* a result from logic):

> $F_A$ is always defined and irrational and every irrational $\alpha$ is equal to $F_A$ for exactly one $A$.

See [here](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/number-theory/infinite-continued-fractions/infinite-continued-fractions.html) for a proof. This implies immediately that the map $A\mapsto F_A$ is a bijection from $\omega^\omega$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, and with a bit of thought we can also see that it's continuous in both directions.

---

Note that the proof of the basic fact above is nontrivial. This is the main virtue of the bijection mentioned in my answer to your previous question: it's less natural but much easier to see that it is indeed a homeomorphism.

Comment: @zwim I don't think you read my answer carefully - I used $1+a_i$ instead of $a_i$ to deal with precisely this issue. E.g. taking $a_0=a_1=a_2=...=0$, we get $F_A=\varphi$. I believe my answer is correct as written.

Comment: Is there a continuous bijection between $\omega^\omega$ and entire $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @user122424 Yes - indeed, if $\mathcal{X}$ is any "interesting" (= nonempty and perfect) [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space), then there is a continuous bijection from $\omega^\omega$ to $\mathcal{X}$. I believe this was first proved by Sierpinski; it should be in Kechris' descriptive set theory book. Of course, order matters here - as I noted above, there is not even any *nonconstant* continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\omega^\omega$.